How can any trustee "have no rights"?
Don't these two quotes contradict Footnote 12 below?

Therefore, in the remainder of this book we shall refer to the trustee as the ‘legal owner’ of property. This is a technical use of the term ‘legal owner’ which means that the trustee is vested with all of the common law rights (that is, the ‘legal title’) in the property. It is not being used in opposition to the colloquial use of the word ‘illegal’.†


2.15 Since the trustee has title to the property in question, the trustee has all the rights and
powers that go with having title to the kinds of property in the trust.‡

How is it possible for any trustee "to have no rights"?

12 Although the example in the text involves fragmented ownership, trusts are not always configured in this way. Sometimes, indeed, while the trustee continues to have no rights, nobody else does either [emphasis mine]. For example, I may hold the land on trust so as to house an art gallery. Then, ownership simply disappears. But this raises the same kind of difficulty as fragmentation, namely the prima facie destruction of the land’s marketability; to which the law has responded in the same way, by the device of overreaching, described below.*

If a trustee has "no rights", then Trustee cannot do anything!
How can Trustee without rights  exercise "their functions as trustees"?
Let alone "all the powers of an absolute owner"?      See Trusts of Land and Appointment of Trustees Act (TOLATA) 1996, s 6

(1) For the purpose of exercising their functions as trustees, the trustees of land have in relation to the land subject to the trust all the powers of an absolute owner.

† Alastair Hudson, Equity and Trusts, 10 edn 2022, pg 43.
‡ James Penner, Law of Trusts, 12 edn 2022, pg 20.
*Chapter 10, An Introduction to Land Law (2015 4th ed) by Prof. Simon Gardner (faculty of law, Oxford University).

Do you feel it is saying the powers come from the trust or are that of the trust and the trustee is just carrying them out?

@Tak sorry, I don't understand your comment at all. please dumb it down.

In the case there was a trustee, the trustee does not really have rights, the trust has the rights.

@Tak I just edited post. please see the top two quotations. "the trustee has all the rights"! see why I am flabbergast?

The trustee is doing things for the trust. The trust has the rights.

@Tak did you peruse the first two quotations above? textbooks wrote "trustee is vested with all of the common law rights". and "trustee has all the rights". you appear incorrect?

An example of a case in which the trustee has "no rights" would be a case where the trust prohibits the alienation of the land, through a sale or mortgage, but the land itself is subject to an easement that renders it effectively useless.
For example, in the U.S., when a city uses the power of eminent domain to build a road over your land, the city will often take an easement for a public road over your land rather than seizing absolute fee simple ownership of the land. Land owners on either side of the road will often "own" the land up to the centerline. But you can't disturb the public road in any way without the consent of the city, even to exploit mineral rights in the land (and often there aren't mineral rights under the public road to exploit).
If the trust prohibits you from selling or borrowing against the land subject to the public road easement, the trustee effectively has "no rights" to the property.
This isn't really 100% true. Even in this case, if the city at some date, maybe decades in the future, decided to vacate the road, the trustee would be entitled to possess and use the land that had been subject to the public road easement before the public road was vacated for trust purposes. But that right is remote, contingent, and mostly useless.
The response of the law to this situation is alluded to but not detailed in footnote twelve. A court could declare the terms of the trust prohibiting the trust from selling or mortgaging the property void. It would do so by ruling that it is a restraint on alienation that is void as contrary to public policy. If this public policy rule were invoked to override the trust terms, the trust could, for example, sell the land subject to the public road easement to an investor who might actively be trying to get the road vacated and who is trying to buy up all of the land subject to the public road easement in that area. This would give the trust's interest in that land at least some value.

thanks. can you break down this your long sentence into simpler chunks ?  "The response of the law to this situation, alluded to but not detailed in footnote twelve, would be to declare the terms of the trust prohibiting the trust from selling or mortgaging the property void as a restraint on alienation that is void as contrary to public policy. "


If a trustee has "no rights", then Trustee cannot do anything!

Nope, that's plain wrong. This is a legal text, and you need to use the correct legal meaning of the word "rights". You seem to confuse it with "powers", which is what the trustee needs to do anything.
The immediately preceding sentence gives an example of a right, namely ownership.
